# Generating a list using another list and an index list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the following two list and a smaller list of indices:

```
list1=[2,3,4,6,7]
list2=[0,0,0,0,0]
idx=[1,2]
```

I want to replace the values in list 2 using the values in list 1 at the specified indices. 
I could do so using the following loop:

```
for i in idx:
    list2[i]=list1[i]
```

If I just have `list1` and `idx` , how could I write a list comprehension to generate `list2` (same length as `list1`)such that `list2` has values of `list1` at indices `idx` or `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will call `__contains__` on every call for `idx` but should be reasonable for small(ish) lists.

```
list2 = [list1[i] if i in idx else 0 for i in range(len(list1))]
```

or

```
list2 = [e if i in idx else 0 for i, e in enumerate(list1)]
```

Also, do not write code like this. It is much less readable than your example. Furthermore, numpy may give you the kind of syntax you desire without sacrificing *readability or speed*.

---

```
import numpy as np 

...

arr1 = np.array(list1)

arr2 = np.zeros_like(list1)
arr2[idx] = arr1[idx]
```

Comment: The numpy example throws up the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`. It should be `arr1[idx]`. Then, it works.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to generate list2 by using appending values of list1 at specific indexes. All you need to do this is to check whether the idx list contains any values and then use a for each loop to append the specific list1 values to list2. If idx is empty then you would only append list1[0] to list2.

```
    if(len(idx) > 0):
        for i in idx:
            list2.append(list1[i])

    else:
        list2.append(list1[0])
```